# Запятая после "однако"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли после слова "однако" ставить запятую и если да, то в каких случаях?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Все зависит от того, чем является слово "однако" в предложении.
Если это вводное слово (в значении "тем не менее") и стоит оно в середине предложения, то оно с двух сторон выделяется запятыми.
Пример: *"Вот, однако, и наши гости"*
Если это союз в значении "но", то, как правило, "однако" ("однако же") стоит в начале предложения и запятой не отделяется.
Пример: *"Однако же он пошел в магазин"*
Если это междометие, то "однако", как и в первом случае, выделяется запятыми, либо восклицательным знаком.
Пример: *"Однако! Такого я не ожидал!", "Однако, пора домой".*

Comment: Как узнать всё-таки, междометие или союз в предложении "Однако(,) пора домой"?

Comment: 1."Вот, слава Богу, и наши гости" (замена другим словосочетанием, которое выделяется запятыми).  2. "И всё-таки он пошёл в магазин" (ясно, что запятая не нужна). 3. Вариант с запятой:"Пожалуй, пора домой" (замена близким по смыслу словом; ясно, что запятая нужна, потому что "пожалуй" всегда выделяется запятыми). Комментарий, вижу, не очень убедителен, поэтому и не поместил его в "Ответ"

Comment: Мой вопрос не совсем о том. *Как узнать?" Ответ - анализировать смысл высказывания. Но смысл высказывания выражается, в частности, в знаках препинания. Получается замкнутый круг.

Comment: "Однако же он пошел в магазин". Согласно п. 1 "однако" в данном предложении является вводным словом в значении "тем не менее", а потому должно выделять запятыми.
"Тем не менее, он пошел в магазин" = "Однако же, он пошел в магазин".

Answer (score 2):

Можно, и не только после, но и до.  Например: он, однако, хороший повар.  Но, если "однако" ся имеет значение "но", то запятая ставится перед ним, а после него - нет.  Например: Мы его позвали на праздник, однако он не пришел.  В этом случае "однако" - противительный  союз.