# Ставится ли запятая после "однако"?

Tags: пунктуация

При росте риска инвестиций  инвестору могут предложить более высокую норму прибыли, однако (?)  риск потери инвестируемых денег, безусловно, увеличивается, и это закономерный процесс.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/63/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE Повтор!

Comment: Однако — словечко не из простых! Мне кажется, что можно оставить вопрос: в каждом обычном предложении с "однако" приходится думать и решать, иногда необычно. Здесь стандарты не всегда "проходят".

Comment: Эта фраза уже обсуждалась, в том числе и про "однако" говорилось: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433364/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не ставится, союз ОДНАКО в функции противительного союза (=НО), обычно в начале предложения, между однородными членами и между простыми предложениями в составе сложного.

Сравнить: Надо ж, однако, сказать несколько слов о самом Санине. И. Тургенев, Вешние воды. Но, однако, я попросил бы вас перейти к вопросу, а то времени мало.

Здесь ОДНАКО является вводным словом.

Пример

В России колокольчик под дугой был частью конной упряжи, **однако** далеко не каждый хозяин мог себе позволить купить дорогое литое изделие. [Константин Скворцов., 2004]

Answer (score 1):

**ОДНАКО** (ЖЕ / Ж), **союз**
Употребляется для присоединения предложений или отдельных членов предложения со значением противопоставления, несоответствия предшествующему или ограничения предшествующего(близок по значению союзу "но").

В Вашем предложении запятая после "однако" не ставится, т.к. здесь слово выражает противопоставление и выступает в роли **союза**(его можно заменить на "но"):

**При росте риска инвестиций инвестору могут предложить более высокую норму прибыли, однако риск потери инвестируемых денег, безусловно, увеличивается, и это закономерный процесс.**
Или:
*При росте риска инвестиций инвестору могут предложить более высокую норму прибыли, **но** риск потери инвестируемых денег, безусловно, увеличивается, и это закономерный процесс.*
[**однако**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_504)

*Хоть грустно жить, друзья мои,

**Однако** жить ещё возможно.*

*Это неприятно для нас, **однако** не изменяет общего правила.

Мы не надеялись никогда более встретиться, **однако** встретились.*